# Json data not decoded return nothing php

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I am getting json from mysql database of blob field and i am using laravel framework all things are working good but when i get json from my blob field it's not decoded i think i have mistake in code this is my code.

```
//get refferral json data from copy_referral table its working.
$getReferral = DB::table('copy_referral')
                            ->where('referral','like','%'.$copyid.'%')
                            ->get();

//now from arrays of column i get only referral column of json data
$olref = $getReferral[0]->referral;

$get_referrals = json_decode($olref);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_referrals); //output nothing
echo '</pre>';

$error = json_last_error();

echo $error; //output 4
```

In above code its not decoded i also check by echoing `$olref` variable its have json data like following `$json` but its not decoding.

But when i am copying json to new blank php page and decode it it's working like champ following code is working.

```
$json = '{
    "0": "http://movyo.to/video/ad1gplh57z304",
    "1": "http://movyo.to/video/ad73yef4211k2",
    "2": "http://vodlocker.com/n8q7jzaxpyhy",
    "3": "http://movyo.to/video/ad735dv5hd3v0",
    "4": "http://streamin.to/v5a6zxlij2zi",
    "5": "http://www.thevideo.me/2qyosd0dt53o",
    "6": "http://vidzi.tv/6wmuw3qvzr08",
    "7": "http://movyo.to/video/ada10782v2vr0",
    "8": "http://www.videoweed.es/file/d8859c23eaf73",
    "9": "http://www.movshare.net/video/bd182e62ffb5e",
    "10": "http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/0fd9e30bf962c",
    "11": "http://www.novamov.com/video/ce9e74b1aecde",
    "12": "http://www.cloudtime.to/video/66e1db1166eee",
    "13": "http://www.vidgg.to/video/782f73cba5729",
    "14": "http://youwatch.org/c3is77ykbxxo",
    "16": "http://yourvideohost.com/8w3ey5lfz5ds",
    "17": "http://goodvideohost.com/gz5luq2jze12",
    "18": "http://filenuke.com/f/0P2BnR3",
    "19": "http://www.flashx.tv/4e6ubn60q7mj.html",
    "20": "http://www.filehoot.com/xwr2lh3sp0i9",
    "21": "http://sharesix.com/f/6bRVMy6",
    "22": "http://streamcloud.eu/1cgk44039g8m/Major.Crimes.S04E08.XviD-AFG.avi.html",
    "23": "http://vid.ag/b5stjoqtkdt8.html",
    "24": "http://www.vidbux.to/i3k0ecnibt35",
    "25": "http://vidzi.net/3vv5oob72nia/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "26": "http://neodrive.co/share/file/V40IYZZT3EJ4GMQOMP16BTWML",
    "27": "http://openload.io/f/9Z2MYCC9epo/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4",
    "28": "http://vidlockers.ag/6e1tml029l63",
    "29": "http://vidzi.net/po0xattbhxs5/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "30": "http://vidlockers.ag/24mwl1n5tvfy",
    "31": "http://vidzi.net/fdjl8aafuv3e/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "32": "http://bestreams.net/a941wd2q71da",
    "33": "http://realvid.net/shzwntsumqu6",
    "34": "http://bestreams.net/bkcatdhf68lj",
    "35": "http://www.exashare.com/7bzid007tp1a",
    "36": "http://divxpress.com/k7xeryixfjl3.html",
    "37": "http://clicknupload.com/z4d0gb1mid0j",
    "38": "http://bestreams.net/wkqmjylyzpgj",
    "39": "http://mightyupload.com/s0fgbgjwt1zh.html",
    "40": "http://letwatch.us/v7onrtjq3jad",
    "41": "http://happystreams.net/ms827uubni3c",
    "42": "http://www.flashx.tv/9nq7a5lb7qoa.html",
    "43": "http://filenuke.com/f/6JrLwV6",
    "44": "http://www.filehoot.com/bn6xbg3d02sn",
    "45": "http://www.filefactory.com/file/4jqy67882mwn",
    "46": "http://up2stream.com/?ref=Ryl8c1SyJ22JyS1c8lyR",
    "47": "http://videomega.tv/?ref=Ryl8c1SyJ22JyS1c8lyR",
    "48": "http://www.video.tt/video/nfzue9CCp",
    "49": "http://vid.ag/mj7gcrq8xc50.html",
    "50": "http://www.uploadc.com/vswtubejmei5.htm",
    "51": "http://streamcloud.eu/2b51rs8js0hn.html",
    "52": "http://sharesix.com/f/0z9Qq76",
    "53": "http://realvid.net/o9zy05ucbj1b",
    "54": "http://putstream.com/tfrue0ipq6n9.html",
    "55": "http://zstream.to/f6c030v26os6",
    "56": "http://openload.io/f/dkZXKI9DUqo",
    "57": "http://zettahost.tv/pzvz9mzk9kbe",
    "58": "http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/6095e8f9ceb29",
    "59": "http://www.zalaa.com/e3p8j7mxf90x.htm",
    "60": "http://nosvideo.com/?v=cvgek8bxear0",
    "61": "http://noslocker.com/?v=3v0gf5v7zf3s",
    "62": "http://netu.tv/watch_video.php?v=XD72KWK6RGM7",
    "63": "http://vshare.eu/mgqhn265ce2q.htm",
    "64": "http://neodrive.co/share/file/50PRLCOWHNZUBV0H2GJ6YLZL5",
    "65": "http://mrfile.me/54w0x7tdj2d5",
    "66": "http://www.movshare.net/video/da941071664a8",
    "67": "http://vidup.me/yvksgudclw2s",
    "68": "http://vidto.me/pu0eynnlxfet",
    "69": "http://vidspot.net/kzq8tomv1rcf",
    "70": "http://vidlockers.ag/v95iohn7uqvg",
    "71": "http://happystreams.net/s4q0ujiyp896",
    "72": "http://vidzi.net/nhri0ppo8kkk/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "73": "http://vidto.me/dw0wjy2k32vs",
    "74": "http://realvid.net/o9i8qusus0s6",
    "75": "http://bestreams.net/u4hkan8a3hj0",
    "76": "http://vidzi.tv/qxiudfq4b8wv.html",
    "77": "http://vidto.me/ofjpg5smn12c",
    "78": "http://vidto.me/rwb1x9wh6ewk",
    "79": "http://vidzi.tv/taytftzama7b.html",
    "80": "http://streamin.to/fokium4c04cq",
    "81": "http://thevideo.me/39663j7v6sdw",
    "82": "http://www.vidxden.com/026bncyjz79o",
    "83": "http://www.vidxden.to/026bncyjz79o",
    "84": "http://beta.vidup.me/pdgoaj3c5jrg",
    "85": "http://vidspot.net/nn6uk8mhcrcf",
    "86": "http://www.filehoot.com/huh7f788bhkz",
    "87": "http://streamin.to/q4rn0pyhfdm2",
    "88": "http://streamin.to/sg8ljegeuefp",
    "89": "http://realvid.net/lq3dsbl9ecjz",
    "90": "http://realvid.net/muqjkl2rpoxq",
    "91": "http://nosvideo.com/?v=679qf8rmigrs",
    "92": "http://thevideo.me/ka0utjg8y17p",
    "93": "http://streamin.to/8rslczq1132t",
    "94": "http://sharesix.com/f/64qE4Y0",
    "95": "http://filenuke.com/f/0rjk9e0",
    "96": "http://vshare.eu/ertwks8010mc.htm",
    "97": "http://mrfile.me/4m4p46ft3xw6",
    "98": "http://www.cloudtime.to/video/66357f8793b28",
    "99": "http://vidlockers.ag/1qirri2wnsy6",
    "100": "http://vidzi.net/qea1e0oamq3j/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "101": "http://www.movshare.net/video/70ec24e961398",
    "102": "http://www.neodrive.co/share/file/CIGZCKYIY6MDEQJ42LLMAO4F5",
    "103": "http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/d0b74efddbfb7",
    "104": "http://vidto.me/tadick9zkqg0",
    "105": "http://mightyupload.com/yc4irxzhcocs/major.crimes.408.hdtv-lol.mp4.html",
    "106": "http://bestreams.net/4n2qbgu9524h",
    "107": "http://vidto.me/mypy3otbzrnj",
    "108": "http://thevideo.me/lmma9w4vej1a",
    "109": "http://mightyupload.com/r3g1wbak7y39",
    "110": "http://mightyupload.com/52v47w0yd66e.html",
    "111": "http://streamin.to/b7duvjpi5734",
    "112": "http://bestreams.net/b048r688b4vu",
    "113": "http://vidzi.tv/6wmuw3qvzr08.html",
    "114": "http://thevideo.me/5f0wfuu8eoqf",
    "116": "http://thevideo.me/fwv45xaih5dr",
    "117": "http://vidzi.tv/6s4hy59u464f.html",
    "118": "http://vidzi.tv/al5zfdhn3zcx.html",
    "119": "http://www.vidbull.com/72sv4b5z7jwu",
    "121": "http://www.vidbull.com/5cm3yowq7xdv",
    "122": "http://www.vidbull.com/1uswpsu7ys4x",
    "123": "http://www.vidbull.com/wyy7bgbae47j",
    "124": "http://www.vidbull.com/d4h7du7ydkj9",
    "125": "http://vodlocker.com/kx741bhrcp6l",
    "126": "http://vodlocker.com/yw6dukkoy8xl",
    "127": "http://vodlocker.com/ieakky1w8dsw",
    "128": "http://www.vidbull.com/movweo2ywiwa",
    "129": "http://vodlocker.com/k7gxufb8y1rn",
    "130": "http://vidzi.tv/ica63udxhoww",
    "131": "http://nosvideo.com/mzp0yl9iu70z",
    "132": "http://vidlockers.ag/p5ruxz5kvtb6",
    "133": "http://realvid.net/4rqtsyvytulc"
}';
```

Now when i am checking it on http://jsonlint.com/ and on http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ its give no error its valid json.

This is my code

```
$decode = json_decode($json);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($decode); //output working fine 
echo '</pre>';

$error = json_last_error();

echo $error //output 0
```

Comment: What is $olref here? And $json is not JSON, its just an array of strings.

Comment: your json is valid in php v5.5.9. `$json = {` - is real part of code?

Comment: and i have check by phpinfo() function i have 5.5.26 version what should i do?

Comment: your code looks like this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/511492c120769cdf66fa88447639055f35d5f774

Comment: @deniskorornets i have edit my question i think my all json in mysql are valid and its decoding on my version i think i am doing some mistaken there `$olref = $getReferral[0]->referral;` please help

Comment: What say `var_dump($getReferral[0]->referral)`?

Comment: If I just decode your JSON-String its working. You should `var_dump($getReferral);`

Comment: i get string(6342) json data when var_dump($getReferral[0]->referral)

Answer (score 1):

If the error is 4, Its json_syntax_error. 
Check whether the json is valid through, http://jsonlint.com/ 
All d best. !
As far as I checked, Your json is not valid.

Comment: its give me error Parse error on line 2:
.../5umy2j32y88f",    "http:/\/\movyo.to/\
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: edit your json , using this editor. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
Accept this as answer if it works. :)

Comment: i have got another json it also not decoded and jsonlint.com give valid json to it what should i do

Comment: suresh point not working now i am editing my full question please see it after 2 min

Comment: i have edit my question i think my all json in mysql are valid and its decoding on my version i think i am doing some mistaken there $olref = $getReferral[0]->referral; please help

Comment: i vote your answer you done great please understand my question my decoding working but not when i get from mysql object $getReferral[0]->referral;

Comment: In my opinion this is not an answer, its a comment. just like the other 'answers'

Answer (score -1):

`$olref` contains non-json string or other value. Check it. It can be boolean, null or another value

Comment: i get this from var_dump($get_Referral)string(6342) "json data"